# Send data between activities with custom variable

Tags: android, variables, android-intent, gwt-activities

How can I send data, using a custom variable type I created, between activities?
I have checked and the "putExtra/putExtras" option does not allow me to send my custom made variable, it only allows string/boolean/int/....

Answer (score 1):

Use a Bundle and make your custom variable Serializable.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("key", CustomVariableObject());
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to serialize your object

```
intent.putExtra("MyData", data);

getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyData");
```

you can see more informations in this post

[How to pass an object from one activity to another on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android)